# Convert JS to autoload

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I use

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    $("#output").load("https://somesite.com/Search.html");
    });
});
</script>
<body>
    <div class="formClass">
        <div id="output">
        </div>
        <button type="button">Search</button>
    </div>
```

to implement an offsite html into my current page.
Howevee this way, the visitor is required to press the "Search" button to reveal the content.

Is there a way to 'automatically' load this, without user interaction ?
(I know a way to trigger the button at siteload, but I'd rather have the button not be there in the first place)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `load` call out of the `click` event listener:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#output").load("https://somesite.com/Search.html");
});
</script>
<body>
    <div class="formClass">
        <div id="output">
        </div>
        <button type="button">Search</button>
    </div>
```